# How do I read a file and change every line in it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to read a multiline txt file and do some manipulations with each line.
I'm trying to use readline but I can't figure out how to use the lines it reads.
Here I use the most standard readline code:

```
const readline = require ('readline')
const fs = require ('fs')

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('price.txt'),
    
})

rl.on('line', function(line){
    
    console.log(line)
})
```

Comment: https://geshan.com.np/blog/2021/10/nodejs-read-file-line-by-line/

Comment: Read the file line by line, write contents to tmp file, replace original file by tmp file when finished.